# Not able to get desired search results in ElasticSearch search api

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, apache-atlas

I have field "**xyz**" on which i want to search. The type of the field is **keyword**. The different values of the field "xyz "are -

- a/b/c/d
- a/b/c/e
- a/b/f/g
- a/b/f/h

Now for the following query -

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "(xyz:(\"a/b/c\"*))"
        }
    }
}
```

I should only get these two results -

- a/b/c/d
- a/b/c/e

but i get all the four results -

- a/b/c/d
- a/b/c/e
- a/b/f/g
- a/b/f/h

**Edit -**
Actually i am not directly querying on ElasticSearch, I am using this API https://atlas.apache.org/api/v2/resource_DiscoveryREST.html#resource_DiscoveryREST_searchWithParameters_POST which creates the above mentioned query for elasticsearch, so i dont have much control over the elasticsearch query_string. What i can change is the elasticsearch analyzer for this field or it's type.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to let the `query_string` [parser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_regular_expressions) know you'll be using regex so wrap the whole thing in `/.../` and escape the forward slashes:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "xyz:/(a\\/b\\/c\\/.*)/"
    }
  }
}
```

Or, you might as well use a [`regexp` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax):

```json
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "xyz": "a/b/c/.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually i am not directly querying on ElasticSearch, I am using this API https://atlas.apache.org/api/v2/resource_DiscoveryREST.html#resource_DiscoveryREST_searchWithParameters_POST which creates the above mentioned query for elasticsearch, so i dont have much control over the elasticsearch query_string. What i can change is the elasticsearch analyzer for this field or it's type.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: You could also use a [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) but when you don't have *any* control over the queries, it's going to be difficult...